# eclipse plugin/rcp: configure driver defintions similar to jdbc

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

i am writing an eclipse plugin that will connect to a server (no database!).
for each platform and each release of said server there will be a different jar to use for connecting and a different set of .dll/.so files used by said driver jar.

i'd like to create a mechanism like the one for jdbc drivers allowing the user to create a profile for a specific configuration of platform/release and select an existing profile to create a connection to a specific server.

thus, it is pretty much similar to what most databse plugins do where one can configure different jdbc drivers for different databases and use such a profile to create a databse connection.

maybe i haven't found the right search terms, but so far i failed to get an example how to write this kind of mechanism.

can someone please point me to a working example for eg jdbc?

to summarize:
- store location of jar
- store location of native shared libraries (dll/so)
- when connection export the location of the shared libs  (at least in linux i currently need to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH) and use/load the configured jar

Answer (score 0):

I cannot point you to a working example, but I would suggest to define an **extension point** in your core application. For each configuration create a "driver plug-in" which implements an **extension** to this extension point. In those driver plug-ins you could bundle the platform specific dlls and so on. Concerning platforms (operating system level) additionally consider to user [**fragments**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_plug-in_fragment?). For more details on how to implement your own extension point look [Eclipse FAQ How do I declare my own extension point?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_declare_my_own_extension_point?)

In the core application you can programatically query all extensions (driver plug-ins) which are available and for example let the user choose which configuration he would like to use via a dropdown box .